Swagger throws a Conflicting method/path combination when using default actions on controllers
I'm using Swagger on ASP.NET Core 8.0 to document my API routes.
The typical template I use is a Controller with the routes defined as attributes like such:
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]/{action=Index}")]
public class ConfigurationController(IConfigurationService _config) : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string key)
    {
       return Ok(await _config.GetSettingOrDefault(key));
    }
}

This is so that I can do a GET with routes like /api/configuration?key=bookingPref.
Yet when I try to fetch the Swagger JSON file, I get this exception:

SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/configuration/{action}" for actions - Rhb.Platform.Controllers.API.ConfigurationController.Index (Rhb.Platform),Rhb.Platform.Controllers.API.ConfigurationController.TenancySettings (Rhb.Platform),Rhb.Platform.Controllers.API.ConfigurationController.DtInfo (Rhb.Platform). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

It appears to me that Swagger doesn't like the default action in the route template.
When I change the route attribute on the controller to this:
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

it works and I get the JSON generated. I could swallow my pride and just do GET on the Index route renamed to GetSetting, but I would rather have the default action defined as a GET on the Index of each controller, avoiding a repeat of the HTTP verb in the path.

[apiController] [Route("api/[controller]")] remove the action object from there and add with the HttpGet method like [HttpGet("index")] and for every HTTP request use a unique name
